# ASP.NET problem: assembly file not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, arcgis, esri

I'm a newbie in the GIS and ASP.NET world and I'm trying to run this tutorial: http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/serveradf_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000200000025000000

I'm failing with the following error:

```
Could not load 'ESRI.ArcGIS.3DAnalyst, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fc3cc631e44ad86' assembly or one of its dependencies. File not found.

Error in the source code:

Line 37:                <add assembly="Microsoft.mshtml, Version=7.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
Line38:                 <add assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=3.0.30930.28736, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28F01B0E84B6D53E"/>
Line 39:                <add assembly="ESRI.ArcGIS.3DAnalyst, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8FC3CC631E44AD86"/>
Line40:                 <add assembly="ESRI.ArcGIS.3DAnalystUI, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8FC3CC631E44AD86"/>
Line41:                 <add assembly="ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8FC3CC631E44AD86"/>
```

I can't load any of the ESRI assemblies.

The assemblies I need are located in the

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\DeveloperKit10.0\DotNet
```

folder, I tried adding assemblies in the GAC cache and adding this path to the .NET Framework\AssemblyFolders registry key but nothing worked. I also tried to change user identity for the application pool.

Any idea on how to solve please?

Comment: Have you tried flagging the `Reference` property `Copy Local` to true?

Comment: Have you tried to copy assemblies to application BIN folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to enable iis to run 32bit applications:

http://blog.davidyack.com/journal/2008/5/19/iis7-and-32bit-applications.html

Comment: Wouldn't the error then be `BadImageException` if it was a bitness related issue?

Comment: Thank you this was just the problem! I wonder why this was not written in the error log.. thank you again